# Clickhouse. Ранжирование выборки

Tags: clickhouse

Есть таблица с колонками  `id`, `color`, мне нужно просуммировать цвета по каждому `id` (с этим проблем нет) и проранжировать их, выбрав ТОП 10 `count_color` по каждому `id`.

В итоге, на выходе я хотел бы получить что-то вроде:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нашел функцию `rowNumberInAllBlocks()`, но не знаю как ее применить, чтобы получить необходимый результат.

```
SELECT *
from (
  SELECT rowNumberInAllBlocks() AS rowNo,
         *
  FROM (
        select id,
               color        as color_id,
               count(color) as count_color
        from db
        group by id, color
        order by count_color desc, id
```

На выходе просто получаю ранк по все строкам, а не в разрезе `color`.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать синтаксис `LIMIN n BY`:

```sql
select id, 
    color, 
    count(color) as color_count
from db
group by id, color
order by id, color_count desc
limit 10 by id
```

Также полезные ссылки:

- [Added support of LIMIT n, m BY clause. #5138](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/pull/5138)
- [DOCAPI-6554: LIMIT BY. EN review. RU translation. #5425](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/pull/5425)